# How do query and then kill a service in a batch file (newbie)

Tags: cmd

I am trying to kill specific services using the PID from "SC QUERYEX wuauserv". But I don't know how to pull the PID shown in the results to then run "taskkill /pid /f [PID]". I am trying to make a batch file which I can use on multiple machines remotely.

I have tried a couple of suggestions made in other similar questions found on google, but wuauserv is not being killed for some reason.

```
@ echo off

cmd /c FOR /F "usebackq tokens=2 skip=3" %%i IN (tasklist /fi "services eq wuauserv") DO taskkill /PID %%

pause
```

The above is what I have, but it's not finding the specific service in the task list. Can anyone assist?

Comment: You don't need `cmd /c`. [for](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) syntax is `for ... in ('command') do ...` (note the single quotes). You missed a char at the end: it's `%%i`

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, because you specified `usebackq` you need to put your Command within backticks  ie: `` IN (`Command`) DO `` () you also need to include the variable letter you specified earlier in the ending section which you have, right now it is just `%%` given you set up `i` as the variable letter it should be `%%i`.

Also the `CMD /C portion` is just not needed at all.

Thats said, just drop the `UseBackQ` it isn't necessary, here is yoru code cleaned up a little.

```
@(
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  echo off
)

FOR /F "Tokens=2" %%I IN ('
  Tasklist /fi "Services eq wuauserv"
  ^| FIND /I "wuauserv"
') DO (
  ECHO Killing PID %%I
  Taskkill /PID %%I
)

PAUSE
```